# Cannot flag answer as low quality

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flagging

So I was on my mobile, and when I try to flag an answer low quality isn’t there. It was there before but now it isn’t:

[image: flag menu]

Is this intentional behaviour? Am I missing something? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Very low quality" flags can only be raised within the first 7 days after a post got created, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326585/unable-to-flag-as-very-low-quality-for-answers

Comment: Ok thanks. Should status-bydesign be added to this post then?

Comment: @DManokhin Done. Regarding VLQ flags: If you see a low quality post please look for ways to edit the post first before you consider flagging. Usually it doesn't require mod functionality to improve posts :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.